# Generate String From List

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to take the values from the following list and insert them into a string. This is the format of the list:

```
[{u'level': {u'status': u'Automatic', u'lastReportedAt': u'2016-05-09T06:37:26Z', u'lowPercent': 10, u'highPercent': 10}, u'color': u'Black', u'type': u'Economy', u'carId': u'319142c0-c2dc-4498-8cb0-0cc9babdee56', u'engineNumber': u'24B6035', u'rrfType': u'Cab'}
```

The output string should be something like this:

```
"Your car is an Automatic, Black, Economy".
```

The "Automatic", "Black", and "Economy" values are all values from the list. This will be running in Python 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for car in carList:
    print("Your car is a {}, {}, {}.").format(car['level']['status'], car['color'], car['type'])
```

---

**Edit to address the comment**

```
t = ""
for car in carList:
    t += "Your car is a {}, {}, {}. ".format(car['level']['status'], car['color'], car['type'])
t[:-1]
```

Comment: Is their a way to output the results from all twelve rows into one string? The current output is a string for each row. So when this runs it prints "Your car is (value), (value),(value)'" twelve times. Is their a way to make it print one string that has the values for all twelve cars? So it would be "Your car is ((value1), (value1), (value1)), ((value2), (value2), (value2) .....)

Comment: @EricCrowley made an edit to demonstrate how to add everything to one string